# Ticket refund for a return ticket from Turkish Airways

Tags: air-travel, tickets, refunds

I study in north Cyprus and I bought a refundable return ticket when coming here from Nigeria but I'm not going to be needing it because I won't be coming home at that date. Someone back home is supposed to collect the refund but the Turkish airline back in Nigeria said they'll need authorization. Please how do I go about it and do I need to present my residency permit or any other document? Do I go to Turkish Airways at the airport or any other office?

Comment: This sounds like a question you should ask Turkish Airlines.  Why not give them a phone call?

Answer (score 2):

Well,

I flew with them few times & need to cancel my trip to London. Had no problem in refund process  (But i bought from sales office indeed and currently live in Istanbul so its very close to me :) )

If you bought an online ticket you can cancel it through their website

http://www4.thy.com/customercontact/Start.tkf (Thats their customer form)

Otherwise if you bought it via a sales office or credit card you should contact related sales office bro.

http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/corporate/turkish-airlines/contact/customer-relation-call-center/sales-office

But all tickets rules can vary so better contact them both ways or you can write their Facebook Page. Here's whole their contact info. Sales offices & phone numbers..etc.. Hope it helps.

Cheers

Kenneth Johannesen